# Build for production cannot allocate memory

Tags: ubuntu, webpack, digital-ocean

I have a standard droplet created on DigitalOcean. Yes its very basic, 1GB ram and 1 core. When running webpack build for development mode, everything is okay - CPU rates not exceeds the 30%. The bundle is getting generated very quickly - something like 10 seconds.

When doing the same thing on the same project, but for production (`mode: "production"`) the whole user process is shutting down and the server is stuck during the task.

Is the production build is so heavy? Is there any way to make it simpler as just as the dev mode?